# In Unity3d, How can I read the position data from .txt file continuously?

Tags: parsing, text, unity-game-engine, text-parsing, continuous

In Unity3D, I want to load position data from text file. Here is an example of the text file. These are simulation results. The simulation program generate 30 data per a second. So, I want to visualize result in realtime. The contents are x, y, z position.

data_01.txt

1 -5 -10

data_ 02.txt

2 2 5

data_03.txt

3 2 4

...............

All files consist of 1 line.

I'd like to input these data into a object.

I want to load text file in 30 text files per 1 second.

I write code that read first text file.
But, I need some advice about reading text file continuously. I want to read 1 text file per frame.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class parsing : MonoBehaviour {

    public string fileName = "Data_01.txt"

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            Debug.Log(fileName + "does not exist.");
            return;
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            String fileData;
            fileData = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

            Debug.Log("Data Read: " + fileData);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have seen almost same question here asked like few days ago :)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question over and over again - if you have more information to add, kindly edit your original question. Do not repost a slightly modified version of your question as a brand new one.

Comment: Note: If you feel this question has significantly changed since your previous one, please explain how. Explain what new things you have tried, and what problems you are now facing as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfering continuous data via text files is a pretty bad idea/approach.

You are better off using (for example) a tcp connection and send your simulation data to unity using .Nets' `System.Net.Sockets` (more precisely `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`).

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets(v=vs.110).aspx

(If you want to stick to your approach, you would have to know the name of the text files to read each `Update()`. You could use a counter variable (name it counter for example), that is incremented each `Update()`. That way you can glue together the current text file name like `string filename = "data_" + counter.ToString("D2") + ".txt"`. (The `ToString("D2")` will add leading zeros if the value of counter is only one digit, e.g. 1 -> "01")